# Is it possible to configure external authentication middleware at run time in asp.net core?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I have use the external authentication middleware in my Asp.Net Core web application like this:

```
app.UseGitHubAuthentication(new GitHubAuthenticationOptions() {
    AuthenticationScheme = "Github",
        SignInScheme = "Identity.External",

        ClientId = "ClientId",
        ClientSecret = "Secret"
});
```

This is middleware which is registered in `Startup` class.

I would like to configure this Github external provider with storing this settings into database via `Entity Framework Core` and after updating these data in database update for example `ClientSecret` and application will be reflected these changes.

Is it possible to store these information about Github middleware into database and update it at run time?

Comment: Create an abstraction that accesses the information and inject it (the abstraction) into the middleware. This would how ever have a slight performance hit is it has to check for that frequently, but there are ways to work around having to pull it from the database every time.

Comment: @Nkosi Can you create some example of your idea, please? Thank you